# Wordpress adding javascript to native wordpress post/page editor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I never used SharpSpring ever, and never really added JavaScript straight into the native editor before, usually have a plugin for what I need. What would be the best practice in adding this into my page.

```
    <!-- SharpSpring Form for Contact Us  -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ss_form = {'account': 'M7M0MDQ3BwA', 'formID':'M7EwNEkyNE3WNTBPNdI1SUox0U00SrTUTbNMS00ySTIxtzAyBAA'};
    ss_form.width = '100%';
    ss_form.height = '1000';
    ss_form.domain = 'app-AUG8DBZI.sharpspring.com';
    // ss_form.hidden = {'Company': 'Anon'}; // Modify this for sending hidden variables, or overriding values
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://koi-AUG8DBZI.sharpspring.com/client/form.js?ver=1.1.1"></script>
```

I tried looking into many different tutorials, but when I try to hook  using wp_enqueue_script() method into my function.php my theme craps out. Not sure what I am doing wrong and looking for guidance on how to add this in to the native editor, and the reason behind it.

Comment: Try your theme's footer.php, or the page template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open that script you can see it uses `document.write()` to insert an iframe in the page.

Since `document.write()` needs to be used at the exact location in the source where the element needs to be inserted you can't register this script through wordpress.

My suggestion would be create a `short code` that can be utilized in WP Admin to instert this form and add the appropriate short code function to add the script tags to the page.

Also  note that `document.write()` is also considered a security hole